# iOS Storekit causing crash in live app

Tags: ios, crash, in-app-purchase, storekit

I get this crash in my live app for my IAP. I'm stressed out by it since it's a missed revenue opportunity. Can anyone help me understand this crash report?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010
 raw
0
libobjc.A.dylib 
objc_msgSend + 16
1
StoreKit    
__34-[SKProductsRequest _handleReply:]_block_invoke + 52
2   libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
9   UIKit   
UIApplicationMain + 204
10
MyApp   
main.m line 14
main
11
libdispatch.dylib   
(Missing)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on there.

```
0 libobjc.A.dylib   objc_msgSend + 16
1 StoreKit          __34-[SKProductsRequest _handleReply:]_block_invoke + 52
```

If I were you I'd look carefully at your `SKProductRequestDelegate`'s `-productRequestDidReceiveResponse:` method. Although it doesn't show up in the backtrace, sometimes they aren't 100% reliable.

The other thing to look for is to see if that delegate has somehow been released. Crashing in `objc_msgSend` is frequently due to that. Are you using ARC?

Here's an article that should be on every ObjC coder's reading list:

http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html